# Async inside async function bug

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to call simple view and within that I am making another query with the data from the view.

My problem is that I do not get it working ( this only gives me empty objects like this `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]`

any idea would be nice

My Code:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getConnection } from '../../../database/connection';
import { Song, Songs } from '../../../utils/song';

export default async function getPeople(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const connection = getConnection()
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM view3", (err: any, rows: Song[], _fields: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.json({err: err})
            connection.destroy();
        } else {
            const response = rows.map( async(row:Song) => {
                const getIp = async() =>{
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE ((ip = 12.12.142.91}) AND (item = ${row.id}))`,(err:any, rows:any, _fields:any) => {
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(rows)
                            return rows;
                        }
                    })
                }
                

                return { voted: getIp(), id: row.id, vote: row.votes,}
            })
             res.status(200).json(response)
            connection.destroy();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can't simply put `async` on a function and have it act like a promise. The connection query function has a callback, which means you'll need to wrap those calls in promises and resolve/reject accordingly.

Comment: @xdumaine phix asn't the downvoter, i simply found your question quite unclear. What is giving you that output? what output did you expect? Why is getPeople async? How is this function being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await anything async, and since `rows.map` is given an async function, it's returning an array of promises, and you must use `Promise.all`

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getConnection } from '../../../database/connection';
import { Song, Songs } from '../../../utils/song';

export default async function getPeople(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const connection = getConnection()
  try {
    // wrap the callback function in a promise
    const rows:any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => connection.query("SELECT * FROM view3", async (err: any, rows: Song[], _fields: any) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);     
      }
      resolve(rows);
    }));
    const getIp = async(id: string) =>{
      // convert the callback function to promise style syntax
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE ((ip = 12.12.142.91) AND (item = ${id}))`,(err:any, rows:any, _fields:any) => {
          if(err){
            return reject(err);
          }
          return resolve(rows);
        })
      });
    }
    const response = await Promise.all(rows.map(async(row:Song) => {
        return { voted: await getIp(row.id), id: row.id, vote: row.votes };
    }));
    res.status(200).json(response)
    connection.destroy();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.json({err: err})
    connection.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: weirdly enough the voted part of the object is never shown, when loggin inside the getIp i never get to the console.log(row). even logging inside the await promise.all it is undefined. any idea why

Comment: I missed an issue when I posted my answer. I updated to refactor a bit to ensure callbacks are promisified.

Comment: thank you, it seems like you have a syntax error at the end of the getIp function. I do not seems be find the fix for it

Comment: still got ',' expected. at const getIp = async(id: string) =>{

Comment: @MaximeGhéraille I think I caught that one too, but what editor are you using? Can you fix syntax errors? I don't have this open in a project, just using the stackoverflow editor, so minor typos are possible, but you should be able to fix them I think. I'm not giving you 100% working code, just showing you how you can restructure to fix your async issues.

Comment: jep I just made a change in your code, it all works now, thx